# How to read href attribute with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use  `$(this).attr('href')` in JQuery to read the string in href="" attribute.
I have those kind of links:

```
<a href="1"></a>
<a href="2"></a>
<a href="3"></a>
```

Firefox and Chrome return me the code correctly. IE return me: `http://127.0.0.1/1`

How can i do?

Comment: what version of IE are you using? Mine works fine with IE 7+ see: http://jsfiddle.net/8rdch/

Comment: you hrefs are relative path? maybe you can replace the hrefs into `/1`, `/2`, `/3`

Comment: i'm using internet explorer 8.0.76

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use the `attr` function when you're accessing a native property. You could use the anchor element's properties directly to get the pathname (i.e. the HREF without the domain or query string)

Basically: `this.pathname`

There's a bit of an inconsistency between browsers (some will show a leading forward slash in `pathname` and others won't). To get around this, just get rid of any potential leading slashes:

`this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')`

A working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/3ET6p/

Even if you choose the other answers, I recommend you use the native `.href` on the object.

---

Just as an extra note to this. I fired up a VM of IE6 and all is well :)

Answer (score 1):

Try via DOM element:
`$(this)[0].href;` or `$(this)[0].getAttribute("href");`

If the result is still the same, I suggest you using something not starting with the number.

.

Comment: You don't even need to wrap it in the jQuery object. Just plain `this.href` will work and saves a bit of processing :)

Comment: That's true. I don't know how to explain, but I somehow tried to demonstrate how to extract a DOM element from jQuery object. And... uh, ended up wrapping a DOM element with jQuery and then .. well, returning it. :D

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest checking which browser is being used. If it's IE, check if the current domain is "127.0.0.1". If it's not, do what @Saul suggested.